# Не работает цель javascript-событие на яндекс метрике

Tags: yandex-metrika-api, яндекс-метрика

Здравствуйте, не выходит установить цель яндекс метрики на кнопку.
Консоль при нажатии на кнопку выдает вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я установил код на кнопку

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="yaCounter32321031.reachGoal('Forma'); return true;" value="Отправить">
```

А вот общий код метрики

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(d, w, c) {
            (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
                try {
                    w.yaCounter45123723 = new Ya.Metrika({
                        id: 45123723,
                        clickmap: true,
                        trackLinks: true,
                        accurateTrackBounce: true,
                        webvisor: true
                    });
                } catch (e) {}
            });

            var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                s = d.createElement("script"),
                f = function() {
                    n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
                };
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.async = true;
            s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

            if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
                d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
            } else {
                f();
            }
        })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");

    </script>
    <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/45123723" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка, пожалуйста

Comment: Номера счетчиков у вас не совпадают